# OData Simple.OData.Client V3 sends other request

Tags: c#, .net, odata, simple.odata.client

I am using Simple.OData.Client V3 for getting some data from odata service, which is hosted remotely. Here is what I am doing but for unknown reasons odata client is sending another request

OData client initialization

```
public ODataClient CreateClient(bool isPost = true)
{
    var uri = new Uri(ServiceAddress);
    return new ODataClient(new ODataClientSettings(uri)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password),
        PayloadFormat = !isPost ? ODataPayloadFormat.Json : ODataPayloadFormat.Atom
    });
}
```

Get request

```
public async Task<GetCustomersResponse> GetCustomers()
{
    var client = CreateClient(false);

    var x = ODataDynamic.Expression;
    var response = await client.For("Catalog_Контрагенты").Top(10).FindEntriesAsync();

    var raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response).ToString();
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerItem>>(raw);

    return new GetCustomersResponse()
    {
        Items = obj
    };
}
```

instead of sending

```
http://odataservice/Catalog_Контрагенты
```

it sends

```
http://odataservice/Catalog_АвансовыйОтчетПрисоединенныеФайлы
```

I also tried sending request in this way and it works correctly

```
public async Task<GetCustomersResponse> GetCustomers()
{
    var client = CreateClient(false);
    var response = await client.FindEntriesAsync("Catalog_Контрагенты?$top=10");            

    var raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response).ToString();
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerItem>>(raw);
    return new GetCustomersResponse()
    {
        Items = obj
    };
}
```

but I don't understand what is wrong with previous sample.

Same thing happens when I am trying to update or add new customer
It sends other request.

### UPDATE 1

This is Fidller request when it sends incorrect request

```
GET http://hostname/odata/standard.odata/Catalog_%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B?$top=10 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, application/text
Prefer: return-no-content
Authorization: Basic d2FuZGlvOjEyMzQ=
Host: hostname
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 185
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 05 May 2016 06:58:27 GMT

{
"odata.metadata": "http://hostname/odata/standard.odata/$metadata#Catalog_АвансовыйОтчетПрисоединенныеФайлы",
"value": []
}
```

And here is request that works correctly

```
GET http://hostname/odata/standard.odata/Catalog_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B?$top=10 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, application/text
Prefer: return-no-content
Authorization: Basic d2FuZGlvOjEyMzQ=
Host: hostname
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 28626
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 05 May 2016 09:40:21 GMT

{
"odata.metadata": "http://hostname/odata/standard.odata/$metadata#Catalog_Контрагенты",
"value": [{
"Ref_Key": "f9210ba9-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09",
"DataVersion": "AAAAAAAki8I=",
"DeletionMark": false,
"Parent_Key": "ca28c1de-af9e-11e1-a90b-00155d01bf04",
"IsFolder": false,
"Code": "002879   ",
"Description": "შპს პრაიმ ქემიქალს1",
"ИНН": "404867569",
"КодПоОКПО": "",
"КПП": "",
"НаименованиеПолное": "შპს პრაიმ ქემიქალს",
"БанковскийСчетПоУмолчанию_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"ДоговорПоУмолчанию_Key": "f9210baa-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09",
"КонтактноеЛицо_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"ФизическоеЛицо_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"СчетУчетаРасчетовСПокупателем_Key": "552c3f13-4ae6-48a3-a9e2-5ce660958242",
"СчетУчетаАвансовПокупателя_Key": "d38b5a6a-be8b-4c2b-8702-57ea8e02e3e6",
"СчетУчетаРасчетовСПоставщиком_Key": "9d195613-e9b0-4dd9-959d-72fd653ac7fc",
"СчетУчетаАвансовПоставщику_Key": "5060faf9-602e-478c-be88-7145c6f48586",
"Ответственный_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"Комментарий": "",
"ВестиРасчетыПоДоговорам": true,
"ВестиРасчетыПоДокументам": true,
"ВестиРасчетыПоЗаказам": true,
"ВестиУчетОплатыПоСчетам": true,
"ЮрФизЛицо": "ЮрЛицо",
"АдресЭП": "",
"Нерезидент": false,
"КонтактнаяИнформация": [],
"ДополнительныеРеквизиты": [],
"Parent@navigationLinkUrl": "Catalog_Контрагенты(guid'f9210ba9-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09')/Parent",
"ДоговорПоУмолчанию@navigationLinkUrl": "Catalog_Контрагенты(guid'f9210ba9-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09')/ДоговорПоУмолчанию",
"СчетУчетаРасчетовСПокупателем@navigationLinkUrl": "Catalog_Контрагенты(guid'f9210ba9-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09')/СчетУчетаРасчетовСПокупателем",
"СчетУчетаАвансовПокупателя@navigationLinkUrl": "Catalog_Контрагенты(guid'f9210ba9-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09')/СчетУчетаАвансовПокупателя",
"СчетУчетаРасчетовСПоставщиком@navigationLinkUrl": "Catalog_Контрагенты(guid'f9210ba9-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09')/СчетУчетаРасчетовСПоставщиком",
"СчетУчетаАвансовПоставщику@navigationLinkUrl": "Catalog_Контрагенты(guid'f9210ba9-cbf8-11e1-8023-00155d01bf09')/СчетУчетаАвансовПоставщику"
}
```

[metadatainfo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1pTJBbFDIirOWhyeXZCaXp1Slk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please skip all the irrelevant code (anything handling the return values is irrelevant as the question is purely about the URL of the request) and instead add the relevant metadata elements?

Comment: @TomTom I added request response classes. Just missed correct response and will update question later

Comment: Well, nice. MORE USELESS STUFF ADDED. Please add the relevant metadata.

Comment: Sorry but I am little confused about what metadata you are asking, can you please tell me what do you mean in metadata

Comment: Metadata. AS in OData Metadata - the document you get when you ask the Odata for $metadata. It is this what determines what a client sends.

Comment: @TomTom I added link metadatainfo. its xml document that I get when calling http://hostname/odata/standard.odata/$metadata. Is it what you are talking about?

Comment: Simple.OData.Client has bug related to non-latin words and will be fixed in adapter...

Comment: It is generally advisable not to use non latin words for anything API related. One never knows the future - and someone not russian (i think) would have problems even entering the names in their code ;)

Comment: Yeah I know, but problem is that the service is not mine and I am not able to change it. It's 1C Compnay service and I dont think they will ever change this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.OData.Client has bug related to non-latin words and will be fixed in adapter.

Here is this issue [odata client sends wrong request](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/246)